# Datatemplate not showing in ListView after being returned by DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datatemplateselector

I am building a Xamarin Forms app and on one of the screens, I am populating a ListView using an ObservableCollection.  The ItemTemplate is selected using a DataTemplateSelector class which is being hit during debugging and returning a DataTemplate.  However I am not seeing the template displaying on the form when it is opened.  I am currently doing my debugging using the UWP interface.

So far, I've tried adding a ListView that has a simple label item template which also doesn't appear to be working as well.  I see that there is a list view item in the Visual Tree though it only contains a ListViewItemPresenter which contains a CellControl.

The property I am binding to is:

```cs
public Generators.Parameter.ConfigurationList Parameters { get; }
```

ConfigurationList inherits ObservableCollection:

```cs
public class ConfigurationList : ObservableCollection<Configuration>
```

The xaml to display a simple ListView is:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="Test" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The full source is available on github here [TheRandomizer.Mobile](https://github.com/melance/TheRandomizer.Mobile/blob/master/TheRandomizer/TheRandomizer/Views/GeneratorDetail.xaml)

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after submitting my question I figured it out but thought I would leave it in case anyone else runs into this.  The DataTemplate requires a :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="Test" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```